# Is it possible to return data with post method in curl

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to learn curl with php. I know it is possible to send values to another script with post method using curl. But if I want that, after first time sending that values executes there and return again with post method .... is that possible.
Here on my two script:

**Index.php**

> ```
> <?php
> $url = 'http://localhost/curl/test.php';
>
> $post_data = array(
>   'first' => '1',
>   'second' => '2',
>   'third' => '3'
>   );
>
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
>
> $output = curl_exec($ch);
>
> curl_close($ch);
>
> print_r($output);
> ?>
> ```

and **test.php**

> ```
> <?php
> $a = $_POST['first'];
> $b = $_POST['second'];
>
> $c = $a+$b;
> $d = $b-$a;
> $e = $a*$b;
>
> $output =  array(
>   'choose' => $c,
>   'choose1' => $d,
>   'choose2' => $e
>   );
>
> print_r($output);
> ?>
> ```

Here index.php send via post method and I can access that with $_POST['first']. If I want that I transfer $output array from here test.php and can access them as $_POST['choose'] from index.php, is that possible?

Comment: did you try it? it is possible

Comment: I tried to do that but not succeeded. Thought that experts may suggest something useful..

Comment: what is the returned response STRING you have in $output?

Comment: from index.php
Array ( [choose] => 3 [choose1] => 1 [choose2] => 2 )

Comment: so you have $output="Array\n(\n    [choose] => 3\n    [choose1] => 1\n    [choose2] => 2\n)\n";

Comment: This string will take some processing. If you want to have data you can use, then Jason McCreary has the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The response from `curl` will not automattically populate superglobals like `$_POST` as these are set at script load.

You will need to parse the curl response yourself. I suggest you return it in a format that is easily parseable by PHP. For example, [JSON](http://json.org/) using [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

#### Example

Replace your `print_r()` with the following code, respectively.

**test.php**

```
echo json_encode($output);
```

**index.php**

```
$data = json_decode($output, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Could you please give me a little example?

Comment: same result like previous...which I want is echo $_POST['choose'] should output 3.

Comment: Yes, but now `$data` is an actually PHP array versus a string. Use `$data['choose']`, not `$_POST`.

Comment: Please read carefully my question. I want them to return under post method.

Comment: I understand. Curl doesn't work that way nor do I suggesting *making* it work that way. This is a better approach.

Comment: If Curl doesn't work in that way, then I have to find another way..thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Instead of print_r($output); create a function module in test.php handling the data, and returning:

```
return $output;
```

index.php, $output = curl_exec($ch); is correct, you can eventually access the data in the following way:

```
echo $output->choose;
echo $output->choose1;
```

or use the `parse_str()` or `json_decode()` as Jason mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try this? You're missing some steps. As it stands, it will not work. Referencing my answer, is not an answer.